# Includehead loaded and zero headheight by default

Tags: header-footer, geometry

I don't know why i'm getting the current layout
[image: layout]

This is my whole preamble

```
\documentclass[spanish,mexico,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts, bbm, mathtools}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{enumerate, enumitem}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{lmodern} %optimiza algunas fuentes
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

%\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{layout}

%Ref
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\Crefname{section}{Sección}{Secciones}

%Imagenes
\usepackage{caption} %para usar caption con *
\usepackage{svg} %inserta imagenes svg
\svgpath{{./imgs/}} %el path de svg

%Figuras numeradas
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}

%Ecuaciones numeradas
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

%header >>>----- modify the headheight below ------<<<
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
% \fancyheadoffset{0cm}
% \setlength{\headheight}{26pt} %set to avoid warnings
\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} }
\lhead{\textit{\thetitle} \\ \course{}}
% \rhead{\theauthor}
\rhead{\theauthor}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\allowdisplaybreaks

%redefine @maketitle
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
%   \null
%   \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title{} \par}%
    {\large\itshape \subtitle{} \par}%
    {\Large \course{} \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{cc}%
        \begin{tabular}{c}%
            \@author \\\ifdefined\email \email{}\fi%
        \end{tabular}%
        &
        \begin{tabular}{c}%
            \university{}\\ \@date%
        \end{tabular}%
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    \hrule
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

%== definiciones de mate ==%
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposición}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lema}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corolario}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjetura}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problema}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definición}[section]
\newtheorem*{example}{Ejemplo}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{observation}{Observación}
\newtheorem*{note}{Nota}

\newenvironment{solution}{\begin{proof}[Solución]}{\end{proof}}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

%% declare useful commands ---remember to use \command* to insert implicit \left #\right
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\set}{\{}{\}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}\lfloor\rfloor
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}\lceil\rceil
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}\lvert\rvert

%editar%
\newcommand\course{-}
\newcommand\university{-}
\title{-}
\newcommand\subtitle{-}
\author{-}
\newcommand\email{\url{-}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
```

I really can't figure out the reason what is loading `includehead` somewhere and setting the `headheight` to zero. Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**: I actually found the solution thanks to the help of @David Carlisle for identifying the problematic package and doing some searching. **Don't use the `fullpage` package**, ironicaly, to achieve a fullpage layout. Instead use the `geometry` package like this:

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
```

The answer was found on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267689/problem-with-fancy-header) question.

Comment: the obvious package candidate to affect the page geometry is `fullpage`.

Comment: I tried commenting but it stays the same.

Comment: posting just the preamble makes it harder for people to debug, please post a complete document that produces the layout image that you show so people can reproduce the problem and test changes. Is it enough just to add `\layout
\end{document}` as a test file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify your preamble adding `\showthe` commands around `fullpage` so that it looks like

```
\showthe\headheight
\usepackage{fullpage}
\showthe\headheight
```

then the terminal and log will show

```
> 12.0pt.
l.15 \showthe\headheight

? 
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/fullpage.sty)
> 0.0pt.
l.17 \showthe\headheight
```

showing headheight got set from its default 12pt to 0pt by that package.

If you could not guess which package was causing the problem, simply put a

\showthe\headheight

after the `\documentclass` (to see it is 12pt) and at `\begin{document}` (to see it is 0pt)  and then simply move the debugging `\showthe`  after each package to see which one changes the value)

I do not know what you mean by  "loading includehead" no package of that name is included by the code shown (nor is there a package of that name in texlive that could be included).

Comment: By "includehead" i mean the option in the geometry package described in page 3 of the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf]. Thank you for the advice into debugging the headheight. I found the solution. I will edit my question.